# Text got blurred on Android Webview

Tags: android, css, android-webview

I'm developing a web based app.  I load a page on an android `WebView`.

The issue is, I set a wave border effect to a div using `css3` radial gradient, the page shows correctly on most browsers, and works fine for iOS version app as well.  But on the android app, If I add this style, the page will totally become blurred.  I paste my css code here:

```
wave-l:before{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0px;
    left: -4px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 4px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 4px 8px;
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 4px, circle, $color 4px, transparent 4px);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(100% 4px, circle, $color 4px, transparent 4px);
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 4px, $color 4px, transparent 4px);
}
```

This css will generate a left wave style border.  The blurred pages shown on android WebView is as shown below:

[image]

I'm quite sure it's this css code snippet caused the issue.  So anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Add  the code

```
  android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml  webview used activity.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem for me. Any idea what causes this bug?

Answer (score -1):

It is too late to respond, but I was also getting the blurred issue in webView. I resolved it by adding

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

It may help somebody